# Using R to group values within different vectors so they can be plotted (ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grouping

I have a question about how to group different vectors from a dataframe, in order to compare and analyse them. For example using ggplot2 to plot some graphs. To make it clearer I will provide the type of dataframe I am working with.

```
 ID      Date    |X |Y |Z |   BR
---------------------------------
6001-102| 2016-03| 1| 1| 1|  1.0
--------------------------------
6001-102| 2016-03| 1| 1| 1|  1.0
--------------------------------
6001-102| 2016-03| 1| 1| 1|  1.0
--------------------------------
6044-460| 2016-03| 2| 1| 4|  0.5
---------------------------------
```

The data columns I am focused on here are Date, Z and BR.

The dates are characters containing the month and years, for example 2016-03 and 2015-05, whilst Z is numeric and ranges from 1-8. I am finding this complicated for myself, because what I want R to do is to first group the results by the date (for example looking at only May 2015) and then get the average BR for each level of Z. Z represents different time groups, so if I was using ggplot I would see the average BR for each time group in May.

Can anyone show me a good example or maybe a previous question that is trying to accomplish the same as me? Hopefully with ggplot2? I haven't found one, but I am sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Removed dput as question answered.

Comment: What would help is having a minimal set of data to work with (e.g. the smallest needed to help answer the question).  You can `dput` a subset of data.  That being said, you could use `dplyr` or `data.table` to group and summarize your original data frame with something like the following: Using `dplyr`: `mydf %>% group_by(Date, Z) %>% summarise(avg_br = mean(BR))`. This uses `dplyr` only in this case. Is this roughly what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will had a dput of a subset now to my original post.

When I try dplyr, I get this error message? 

`Error: 'monthly.b' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'`

When using this code:

    `dplyr:: monthly.rate %>% group_by(Date_fill, a6ncopo) %>%          summarise(avg_br = mean(biting_rate))`

Comment: In the mean time I am watching a helpful tutorial on [dplyr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWjqLW-u3hc&list=PL5-da3qGB5IBM6DdZ-ZV8mA0oV0U56xaq)

Comment: Does that mean you have your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mydf %>% group_by(Date_fill, y) %>% summarise(z = sum(z, na.rm=TRUE))